# Weird "Network" folder on lion's sidebar

Tags: macos

After swapping my HDD to an SDD (and using CarbonCopyCloner to clone the disk), there's this weird "Network" folder appearing on my sidebar.

If I click it, it shows a folder for a split second and then it goes back to the previous folder I was in. I can't remove it from the sidebar by right clicking it (it shows no menu).

I attach a screenshot of the problem. Anyone have any ideas?

[image: Weird folder on sidebar]

Comment: If you open Finder preferences and go to the Sidebar tab, does it show Network as one of the items?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how that folder got there but you can try to get rid of it by holding `Command` and dragging it out or trashing `~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.sidebarlists.plist` (it will reset the Sidebar to default) and reboot if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

You say you cloned the disk...

I am not the most knowledgeable when it comes to these things, but it appears to me that, as the icon is the same as the other normal folders in mountain lion, the GUI must see it as a normal folder. (Which means at some point it *was* a normal folder.)

This may be a remnant from Lion, as the data for the Lion network folder will have been copied during the disk clone. However, as Mountain Lion does not support this folder anymore, it has become a ghost, caught in an OS it was never intended to be in.

The brief flicker of a window that appears would be the GUI attempting to open a folder that has no actual existance in your current OS.

Comment: Weird thing is that I'm on Lion, not ML.

Comment: Oh wow. I have no idea then, sorry.